# Password hashing not working on Put request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-hooks, put, password-hash

Using bcryptjs library and got 2 issues when performing Put request:

1- On insomnia / postman, server returns hashed password, but it returns "unhashed" on client side inspect console tools.

2- I can not perform a login with new password credential.

Any visible syntax mistake on server code or quick suggestions please? Tks!

CLIENT SIDE CODE:

```
function DevUpdateForm() {   
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [techs, setTechs] = useState("");


async function updateUser(e) {      
        e.preventDefault()
        const dataUpdate = { name, email, password, techs}
        const response = await api.put(`/devs/${dev._id}`, dataUpdate);   
              console.log(response);
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
        setTechs([]);
    }

        return (               
              <div className="update-profile">     
                <strong>Alterar</strong>
                <img src={dev.avatar_url} alt={dev.name}/>  
                <form onSubmit={updateUser} >
                  <div className="input-block">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Nome:</label>
                    <input 
                      name="name" 
                      id="name" 
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={"Alterar nome"}
                      value={name}
                      onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                      />
                  </div>

                  <div className="input-block">
                    <label htmlFor="email">E-mail:</label>
                    <input 
                      name="email" 
                      id="email" 
                      type="text"
                      placeholder={"Alterar email"}
                      value={email}
                      onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-block">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Senha:</label>
                    <input 
                      name="password" 
                      id="password" 
                      type="password"
                      placeholder={"Digite nova senha"}
                      value={password}
                      onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                      />
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-block">
                    <label htmlFor="techs">Techs:</label>
                    <input 
                      name="techs" 
                      id="techs" 
                      type="text"                 
                      placeholder={"Alterar tecnologias"}   
                      value={techs}
                      onChange={e => setTechs(e.target.value)}
                      />
                  </div>                    

                  <button type="submit" >Salvar</button>
                </form>
              </div>        
        )
    }

    export default DevUpdateForm;
```

SERVER SIDE UPDATE CONTROLLER:

```
    async update(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { name, email, password, techs } = req.body; 
        const { _id } = req.params;
        const techsArray = parseStringAsArray(techs);


        let dev = await Dev.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {
                name,
                email,                        
                password,             
                techs: techsArray                 
        }, 
        {new: true});

        dev = await Dev.findById(_id)

        dev.password = await bcrypt.hash(dev.password, 8)              

        if (dev !== null) {
            res.status(200).send({
                data: dev,
                message: "Dev has been updated!"                   
            });
            } else {
            res.status(404).end();
            }

       } catch (error) {
        next(error)
       }
},
```

ROUTE:

```
routes.put('/devs/:_id', DevController.allowIfLoggedin, DevController.grantAccess('updateAny', 'profile'), DevController.update);
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding the model and set new values to user model. you have to execute **.save()** statement to update existing changes.

```
async update(req, res, next) {
 try {
    const { name, email, password, techs } = req.body; 
    const { _id } = req.params;
    const techsArray = parseStringAsArray(techs);


    let dev = await Dev.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {
            name,
            email,                        
            password,             
            techs: techsArray                 
    }, 
    {new: true});

    dev = await Dev.findById(_id)

    dev.password = await bcrypt.hash(dev.password, 8)              
    dev.save();// add this to save new password
    if (dev !== null) {
        res.status(200).send({
            data: dev,
            message: "Dev has been updated!"                   
        });
        } else {
        res.status(404).end();
        }

   } catch (error) {
    next(error)
   }
},
```

Comment: Thank-you Himanshu! The password now is coming hashed on console and is being saved hashed on MongoDB data based. However I still can not log in with new credentials.  My  login code is working just fine before editing user credentials.

Comment: check  save statement response if there is any error. share it

Comment: No error when editing. All new info updated with a hashed password. The only eror is when trying to login again, I get:                                                                             POST http://localhost:5555/devs/login 400 (Bad Request)